# how to use the ApplicationArguments in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am learning the Spring-Boot(I am new to it), reading the Spring Boot Document. In the **23.6 Accessing application arguments**, It talk about the **ApplicationArguments**, and the code is:

```
package com.example.project;

import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;

import java.util.*;

@Component
public class MyBean {
  @Autowired
  public MyBean(ApplicationArguments args) {
    boolean debug = args.containsOption("debug");
    List<String> files = args.getNonOptionArgs();
    System.out.println(debug);
    System.out.println(files);
  }
}
```

It says if run with "--debug logfile.txt" debug=true, files=["logfile.txt"].

But in my project, I don't know how to run it. I create the spring-boot using Maven: The Project Structure 
[image: the]

Answer (score 6):

In Spring Boot doc `ApplicationArguments` is autowired in a bean. Here is a more hands on example where it's used in a Main method.

```
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args).stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        boolean debug = args.containsOption("debug");
        List<String> files = args.getNonOptionArgs();
        System.out.println(debug);
        System.out.println(files);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have an Application class with annotation @SpringBootApplication like in the answer provided by [a.b.d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802355/how-to-use-the-applicationarguments-in-spring-boot/40600574#40600574).

To be able to provide the arguments within IntelliJ IDEA environment you will need to first Run the main method and then Edit 'Run/Debug Configurations' and under Main Class fill Program arguments field with "--debug logfile.txt":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In one word like a thousand :
the 'Program arguments' in your IDE field prefixed by -- is simply the same name as the 'Option' expected in the 'ApplicationArguments'.

Hence you can match --debug and "args.containsOption("debug")".